# re.split parameters aren't working like guides say?

Tags: python, split, python-re

```
x="3x^2+2x-1"
x=re.split(r"[\^]|([-])|[+]", x)
print(x)
#returns: ['3x', None, '2', None, '2x', '-', '1']
```

I thought it should return something like ['3x','2','2x','-','1']. Sorry, I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding re. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your regex pattern used for splitting has a capture group in there, but it only includes the minus operator.  Just split on the character class `([\^*/+-])` inside a capture group.  This will split on any operator but will also include that operator in the output list.

```
x = "3x^2+2x-1"
x = re.split(r"([\^*/+-])", x)
print(x)  # ['3x', '^', '2', '+', '2x', '-', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [y for y in re.split(r"[\^]|([-])|[+]", x) if y != None]
```

I am not an RegEx wizard, but you can remove all Nones.